# Connection refused error when connecting a WCF to a Xamarin.Android project

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin.android

So I am new to Xamarin and WCF. However, that wasn't gonna stop me from using those new technologies! Anyways, I started with this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/walkthrough-working-with-wcf

I followed it step by step to no avail(numerous errors when building the project). I then decided to use the sample code for the same tutorial provided here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/WCF-Walkthrough/

(click Download on the top right corner).

When running this project (Android part), I get an error "Connection refused". I'm guessing this is a generic error message that occurs even if the WCF wasn't even found (because I changed configurations to test that theory).

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Other things to note:

I have turned my firewall off (just in case).
Based on the tutorial I did all of the IIS changes that were in there. I also made changes to the application.config file to have it contain my IP address.
I have been stuck on this now for 3 days.
It would be really useful to solve this error, because anyone else using that tutorial could also actually get the project working.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: So are you tying this from an actual device or an emulator

Comment: Can you connect to your WCF endpoint, from the WctTestClient

Comment: I'm using an emulator. Yes, I can connect to the WCF endpoint from the WcfTestClient (by selecting HelloWorldService as the startup project I can also run and test the WCF, which works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the emulator, you cant just refer to *LocalHost*. The *Localhost* refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address `10.0.2.2` instead.

More info here

[Set up Android Emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the changes in three places (app.config, applicationhost.config, and MainActivity.cs). I am now getting a new error message which is actually comforting to get a different result. The new error is: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SayHelloTo'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'SayHelloTo' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'SayHelloToAsync' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'

Comment: @james, may i suggest asking a new question, with the new error, otherwise we could be chasing this around all day, unless you think its related to the above answer not working

Comment: Will do. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for finality reasons, this was the solution! I just had to use the svcutil.exe to recreate the references.cs file. How do I mark your answer as the correct one and "close" this question?

Comment: @JamesCarter just upvote, and click the tick next to the quest, glad it worked

Comment: Sorry my upvote doesn't display, but I clicked it several times lol.